# Problemas para autentificarme con Active Directory || "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad credentials"

Tags: spring-security, ldap, directorioactivo

Tengo este codigo en mi archivo de configuración sprin security `@Bean @Lazy public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() { log.info("*************DOMINIOLDAP**********" + domainldap); log.info("***********URL LDAP****************"+ urlLdap); ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domainldap, urlLdap); adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true); adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true); log.info("***********PROVIDER***************"+ adProvider); return adProvider; }` y me deja autentificarme con mis credenciales AD cuando esta en mi entorno local y cuando se despliega en kubernetes en el ambiente de QA, pero cuando se despliega en produccion me sale el siguiente error `{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad credentials" }`

Levante mi servicio en mi entorno local apuntando a las variables de produccion y me genera el token de acceso ,pero desplegado en los contenedores no lo genera y me da un error de credenciales, sigo sin  hallar el error revise las variables de entorno de los contenedores y estan bien configuradas como en QA, necesito ayuda estoy bloqueado